# Get only neighborhoods from Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api

Is it possible to make a request to the Google Places API to get all entries of type "neighborhood" in a radius of n meters from a specific point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, no.  You can get locations of type "neighborhood", but you cannot filter for it at this time.

See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types

Comment: The link you provided is broken. Do you know if this is possible in 2021?